# How to group and fill rows

Tags: r, rows

I am new to R, and need to group and fill rows by similarity. 
 I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name         Job          Gender City  
California   NA            NA     1
Bob          plumber       M      0
Carol        nurse         F      0
Chicago      NA            NA     1
Tom          Chef          M      0
Ann          Swimmer       F      0
Joy          Police        F      0
```

I need the dataframe to look like this:

```
Name         Job          Gender  City
Bob          plumber       M      California
Carol        nurse         F      California
Tom          Chef          M      Chicago 
Ann          Swimmer       F      Chicago 
Joy          Police        F      Chicago
```

Apologies if this is similar to another question asked- again, I am very new to this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming groups begin where `City` equals 1, and using the `NA` values in the `Job` (or `Gender`) column, we can do the following.

```
na.omit(transform(df, City = Name[is.na(Job)][cumsum(City)]))
#    Name     Job Gender       City
# 2   Bob plumber      M California
# 3 Carol   nurse      F California
# 5   Tom    Chef      M    Chicago
# 6   Ann Swimmer      F    Chicago
# 7   Joy  Police      F    Chicago
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Ann", 
"Bob", "California", "Carol", "Chicago", "Joy", "Tom"), class = "factor"), 
    Job = structure(c(NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Chef", 
    "nurse", "plumber", "Police", "Swimmer"), class = "factor"), 
    Gender = structure(c(NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
    "M"), class = "factor"), City = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), .Names = c("Name", "Job", "Gender", "City"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help- this one eliminates the "City" variable altogether, it doesn't group them

Comment: @maggietron - This is exactly what you show for the desired result. And `cumsum(City)` creates the groups.

Comment: And technically, it doesn't eliminate `City` at all. It's there in the `df`. It has been transformed to have values of `['California', 'Chicago']`. It matches your test case perfectly. Don't blame @RichScriven for a bad spec.

Comment: @ShawnMehan It's very possible I've done something prior in my code that's making it not turn out the same way- like I said I don't quite know what I'm doing yet!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi. Try just running, in a new script, the code that RichScriven supplied. If that doesn't match what he posted, there is a different problem somewhere. If it does, then you need to indeed go back and debug the code *before* the transform. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

By using `zoo`, I break down steps

```
library(zoo)
dat1$City[dat1$City==1]=dat1$Name[dat1$City==1]
dat1$City[dat1$City==0]=NA
dat1$City=na.locf(dat1$City)
dat1=dat1[!is.na(dat1$Gender),]

dat1
   Name     Job Gender       City
2   Bob plumber      M California
3 Carol   nurse      F California
5   Tom    Chef      M    Chicago
6   Ann Swimmer      F    Chicago
7   Joy  Police      F    Chicago
```

Comment: This works exactly how I need it to!  The only thing is that I am left with rows that look like this: 
California   NA            NA     California
Chicago      NA            NA     Chicago

Is there a way for me to get rid of those ones as well?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @maggietron so you need keep them or remove them ?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way you could approach this is to use `fill` from the `tidyr` package.

I've added a new variable `City_Name` and retained the original `City` variable (Since the OP's comments indicate they might still want to see that information in the result).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(City_Name = if_else(City == 1, Name, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(City_Name) %>% 
  filter(City == 0)
#>    Name     Job Gender City  City_Name
#> 1   Bob plumber      M    0 California
#> 2 Carol   nurse      F    0 California
#> 3   Tom    Chef      M    0    Chicago
#> 4   Ann Swimmer      F    0    Chicago
#> 5   Joy  Police      F    0    Chicago
```

**Data**

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Name         Job          Gender City  
California   NA            NA     1
Bob          plumber       M      0
Carol        nurse         F      0
Chicago      NA            NA     1
Tom          Chef          M      0
Ann          Swimmer       F      0
Joy          Police        F      0", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```